# Append txt file throughout loop in r - then read that txt file into a corpus with the tm package

Tags: r, text-mining

**The problem:** 
I have a loop that downloads sentences from a webpage – and for each iteration adds them to a growing character vector.

Conceptually, the output looks like this:

```
myVec

[1] "bla"                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[2] "blablabla"                                                                                        
[3] "blabla"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[4] " blablablablabla"
```

Etc…

Each number represents a sentence that I’ve downloaded. For each iteration the loop appends the vector with more sentences.

But instead of having the results go into a vector - I would like to save it to a growing txt file. The reason for this is that the amount of data I need to download is big. So that I need to let the loop run for a while (1000 iterations), then take a break - and then run it again the next day.

And I would like the txt file to have some structure – so that it can still easily be split by sentence. This is because I would later like to create a DTM with each sentence as a separate doc.

**So what I need**

1: a way to write to a file which can be appended with new sentences throughout the loop.

2: A way to read that file with the tm package so that I can later create a DTM based on the sentences I’ve downloaded.

**What I’ve tried:**

The closest I’ve gotten to what I want was using the write.table() function.

```
write.table(MyVec, file = "output.txt",row.names=FALSE, col.names = FALSE, append= TRUE)
```

This seems to give me a text where the sentences are separated by quotation marks:
“bla” 
“blablabla”
“Blabla”
Etc.

But I do not know how to utilize this when reading it into a corpus with tm – in order to later create a DTM based on the sentences. Maybe there is a better way?

I have also tried the write() function:

```
write(MyVec, file="output.txt",append=TRUE)
```

This gives me a growing txt file but it does not seem to separate out the sentences. I Do not know how to read it into a corpus and create a DTM based on sentences.

I’ve considered writeLines() – but it does not seem to have the append option – and anyway: I do not want to break the text up in lines. I only want to separate on sentences.

Comment: set `quote=FALSE` for `write.table` and you'll get rid of the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to store (or load) your list of sentence as a data frame and parse it as vector source with tm().

```
library(tm)

Sentences <- c("First Sentence BLA", "Second Sentence BLA BLA", "Nth Sentence [...] Bla^n")
SentencesDF <- as.data.frame(Sentences)
Corpus <- VectorSource(SentencesDF)
```

In the previous example you didn't need to write the "Sentence" vector into a txt or cvs to get a Corpus. If you still need to do that for other reasons, simply run:

```
write.csv(SentencesDF, file = "NameofFile.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nicolás! I do need to save it down. The reason is that it takes a very long time to fetch all the sentences from the webpage. So I need to be able to interrupt the process and the pick it up the next day (I've updated the post to clarify this). write.csv() does not let me do that; because it does not take the append argument. I've been experimenting with write.table() and write(). But my problem is that I can't find a way to save the results down in a way that makes it easy to recreate the same vector I had to begin with.  One which is split on sentences.

Comment: Ok, so I think of two options. My favorite is to store a DF for each day (ie. Sentences_2017-08-07; Sentences_2017_08_08;...) and when you have finished capturing all your source, append all atomic DFs into one. (i.e. do.call(rbind, lapply(ls(pattern = "Sentences_"), get)).

Comment: The second one is to add a unique character or string at the end of each captured sentence, so later, you will be able to parse each sentence by marking that unique character as a delimiter when reading it back to R.